# Internet Works, but pings all fail, and phones won't connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I am having a very strange situation going on.

All of the following statements are true:

- I can connect wirelessly to my network via my computers.
- I cannot connect to any of the computers on my network via the wired interface
- No phone in my house will connect to the wireless network.  It refuses to get an IP address

These three statements seem completely incompatible with each other.

I have rebooted everything.  I have unplugged and plugged back in everything.  I usually know what I doing around my Ubiquiti network, but this has me flummoxed.  It's not a problem with any particular computer or phone -- they are all behaving the same way.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to describe your network and hardware for meaningful answers. It almost sounds like your DHCP server is not working, and that computers are using a fallback IP while cellphones dont - but this can be no more then a guess on the info provided.

Comment: Can you clarify if both the wired and wirelessly-connected computers have internet access? If either group doesn't have internet access, do they happen to have IP addresses starting with 169.254?